GitHub Action conditional job - depending on variable - skipped
In the code below condition_check_files runs without an error (it was resolved in my prior question). My problem is that conditional_pandoc is skipped on any run. Update: This is resolved, see below
name: conditional_convert_via_pandoc
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'main' # Do the work exclusively for the deploying branch

jobs:
  condition_check_files:
    runs-on: 'ubuntu-22.04'
    # Declare outputs for next jobs
    outputs:
      bool_files_changed: ${{ steps.check_file_changed.outputs.bool_files_changed }}
      list_changed_files: ${{ steps.check_file_changed.outputs.list_changed_files }}
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      with:
        fetch-depth: 2
    - shell: pwsh
      id: check_file_changed
      run: |
        # Look only for changed files (A - added, M - modified) and return their names (the specific changes are irrelevant)
        $diff = git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AM HEAD^ HEAD

        # Filter the files under content/ with the .md extension excluding the Hugo associated _index.md files
        $SourceDiff = $diff | Where-Object { $_ -match 'content/' -and $_ -match '.md$' -and -not ($_ -match '_index.md') }
        $HasDiff = $SourceDiff.Length -gt 0

        # Set the output named "bool_files_changed"
        echo "{bool_files_changed}={$HasDiff}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
        echo "{list_changed_files}={$SourceDiff}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  # Run the job only with 'bool_files_changed' equals 'True'
  conditional_pandoc:
    runs-on: 'ubuntu-22.04'
    needs: [ condition_check_files ]
    if: needs.condition_check_files.outputs.bool_files_changed == 'True'
    steps:
    - uses: docker://pandoc/latex:3.5
    - shell: pwsh
      run: |
        # List types which will only use --standalone. You can easily add more extensions if you're fine with this setting
        $ONLY_STANDALONE_OUTPUT_TYPES = "latex pdf html docx odt"
        # Use as many cores as available to be as fast as possible
        parallel --jobs 0 \
          # Pandoc creates an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree); reuse this by saving to/reading from .ast
          pandoc --from markdown {} --to native -o {.}.ast ';'\
          for i in $ONLY_STANDALONE_OUTPUT_TYPES';' do \
            pandoc --from native {.}.ast --standalone -o '{.}.$i' ';' \
          done';' \
          # You can easily add individual conversion rules by using pandoc after the 'done' part. Keep in mind to finish all non-comment lines with backslash
          rm {.}.ast ::: needs.condition_changed_files.outputs.list_changed_files

I did small changes to a test.md file in content/ and pushed to main, which should fulfill the condition. The job was skipped anyway.
(In the logs is a hint to use git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>, where <name> would be main but I'm not the owner of the user account and I am unsure where to execute that code when it's a git action)
Update
According to @Azeem I did the following changes:
        echo "bool_files_changed=$HasDiff" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT
        echo "list_changed_files=$FilesDiff" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT

and (where I also had to change run: | to run: >)
 conditional_pandoc:
    runs-on: 'ubuntu-22.04'
    needs: [ condition_check_files ]
    if: needs.condition_check_files.outputs.bool_files_changed == 'True'
    env:
          list_changed_files: ${{ needs.condition_changed_files.outputs.list_changed_files }}
    steps:
    - uses: docker://pandoc/latex:3.5
    - shell: pwsh
      run: >
    # [...]
          rm {.}.ast ::: $env:list_changed_files

which results in the new error:
ParserError: /home/runner/work/_temp/69623bdb-8aae-4519-83a6-1eafde9d8570.ps1:4
Line |
   4 |    pandoc --from markdown {} --to native -o {.}.ast ';'\
     |                                              ~
     | Missing expression after '.' in pipeline element.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

which is weird, because at least this bash code (parallel :: pandoc) works locally on my machine

can you add the yaml here and the relevant logs?

Typos! You need to update the command to set the output parameters in Powershell. See docs and the example.

@Azeem The example only shows the env usage within the same job :/ I changed echo "{bool_files_changed}={$HasDiff}" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT (same for list_files_changed) and added (one codeblock for each new line if: needs.condition_check_files.outputs.bool_files_changed == 'True' env:           list_changed_files: ${{ needs.condition_changed_files.outputs.list_changed_files }} steps: [...] rm {.}.ast ::: $env:list_changed_files but it doesn't work either

Are you still using curly braces? Please edit your question and update with what you've tried.

According to your update, the job is not skipped, right? The error you have posted is now in the script.

Yes, the job is no longer skipped. Thus I tripped over the |, which is already resolved
